# getting path of "self" using powershell

Tags: powershell

I know this has to be incredibly simple but everything I'm finding is how to recover the path of another file. What I need to get is the path of the powershell file that is running. That way it can be moved and still function properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

Comment: I'll just add that if you're going to try to get the path of the executing script from within a function the scope of the $MyInvocation variable changes. To get the path from within a function use `$script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`

Comment: Note that in PowerShell V3 you can use the automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot` in script files as well as modules.

Answer (score 1):

$ScriptPath = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand).Path